# Receiving 404 url not found on this server for wordpress multisite on localhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have been searching for over three weeks for a solution with no luck, simply nothing has worked for me yet. After installing multisite everytime I create a new site i get the 404 url not found on this server. Furthermore when i try to reset permalinks for pages on my main site i get the 404 error here as well, only if i leave it as plain am i able to view the pages on the mainsite, but still none of the other sites in my network work. i have tried deleting sites and creating them anew but still no luck. They appear on my network dashboard but i cant access the front end or the dashboard of the actual site.

-I am running a mamp sever on localhost for windows 7

-I have uncommented my rewrite_module in my httpd.conf file and it is being read as shown by the in my php info under the 
[apeche2handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daSi8.png) readout.

-The bottom of my wp-config file looks exactly like this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

-

-My .htaccess file looks exactly like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

- I have changed the allow_overide in my httpd.conf to All and the "directory" portion currently looks like this

  Directory />

  ```
  Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  ```

  /Directory>

-I have searched all other solutions but none seem to fix my specific issue, i truly appreciate any assistance as i hope to finish this project.

Comment: try to stick to what is really essential in your question. it helps with readability and understanding.

Comment: My apologies, i wanted to show my work and fixes i have already attemted, bassically i created a multisite network on localhost using mamp running on windows 7. my permalinks cant be updated to any type except plain. furthermore any new site i create does not work. i get the 404 url not found on this server error message everytime.

Comment: Please can anybody assist me, i have tried every possible solution i could find and nothing works, google has run out of suggestions to my search queries ive been at this for so long. Please anaybody, i am relly enjoying what im learning, and i really want to improve. Thank You in advance